Nest can't resolve dependencies of the I18nService
getting error when i try to run test cases
import { Test } from '@nestjs/testing';

import { appConfig } from '../app.config';
import { CommonBotModule } from '../common/common-bot.module';
import { CredentialsManagerModule } from '../credentials/credentials-manager.module';
import { BotModule } from './bot.module';
import { I18nService } from 'nestjs-i18n';

jest.mock('aws-sdk'); // Prevent DynamoDB connect
jest.mock('@aws/dynamodb-data-mapper'); // Prevent DynamoDB connect
jest.mock('kafkajs');
jest.mock('../cache/cacheConfig.service'); // Prevent Redis connect

describe('bot.module.ts', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
        config.init(appConfig);
    });

    it('The bot module should be able to be compiled', async () => {
        const botModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
            imports: [CommonBotModule, CredentialsManagerModule, BotModule, I18nService]
        }).compile();

        expect(botModule).toBeDefined();
    });
});

error : 
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the I18nService (?, I18nTranslations, I18nLanguages, Logger, I18nLoader, I18nLanguagesSubject, I18nTranslationsSubject). Please make sure that the argument I18nOptions at index [0] is available in the I18nService context.

    Potential solutions:
    - If I18nOptions is a provider, is it part of the current I18nService?
    - If I18nOptions is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within I18nService?
      @Module({
        imports: [ /* the Module containing I18nOptions */ ]
      })


i  am getting error while running jest test cases and only in module.spec files not in ts file where i used I18nService to translate test !

you're registering a 3rd-party provider. That I18nService will be registered by some nestjs module from nestjs-i18n package, so you shouldn't have it in your array.
If you do want to use the I18nService as a provider token for a mock value, you can do:
{
  provide: I18nService,
  useValue: yourFakeObjectHere,
}

There are other ways to achieve that. Read the docs: https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/testing

Hello I tried below one still getting same error
describe('bot.module.ts', () => {
let mock
beforeAll(() => {
mock = {
I18nOptions : jest.fn()
}
config.init(appConfig);
});
it('The bot module should be able to be compiled', async () => {
const botModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
imports: [CommonBotModule, CredentialsManagerModule, BotModule],
providers:[
{
provide: I18nService,
useValue: mock
}
]
}).compile();
expect(botModule).toBeDefined();
});
});
